# Unit test an error thrown inside an Observable subscription

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In an Angular application, I throw an `Error` within an `Observable.subscribe()`. However in my Unit Test the error is not caught, but simply bubbles up and make the test fail.

Here the code I want to test:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.productType = params.get('auftragTyp');
      if (!this.productType) {
        this.router.navigate(['/conversations']);
        throw new Error(`Missing product type!`);
      }
    });
  }
```

And here the Unit Test:

```
describe('TaskComponent', () => {
  let component: TaskComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TaskComponent>;
  let activatedRouteMock = { queryParamMap: new Subject<any>() };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TaskComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TaskComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should NOT navigate to Conversations', fakeAsync(() => {
    activatedRouteMock.queryParamMap.next(convertToParamMap({
      order: 'tool',
      partnerNr: '123'
    }));

    tick(); // wait for resolution
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(routerMock.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/conversations']);

    expect(component.ngOnInit).toThrowError('Missing product type!');
  }));
});
```

I use `fakeAsync` and `tick()` as I need the mock different queryParams from activatedRoute in the tests, hence using a `Subject` and then `fixture.detectChanges()` to emit new query parameters.

---

**UPDATE**

Trying with `throwError`, but same result:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
    .pipe(
      map((p: ParamMap) => {
        if (p.get('auftragTyp') !== null) {
          return p;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/conversations']);
          throw new Error('Missing product type!');
        }
      })
    )
    .subscribe({
      next: (params: ParamMap) => {
        this.productType = params.get('auftragTyp');
        // ...
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: instead of throw new Error() try using throwError() operator of rxjs?

Comment: I tried, but even with `throwError()` the last expect is not matched.